# A function finite almost everywhere but NOT Lebesgue integrable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I was trying to solve a problem on measure theory from the book of Folland and got stuck in one problem(Prob-25,page-59). My comments are in italics.

Let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $L^1(m)$ be the space of all m'ble functions $g$ such that $|g|$ is integrable.

**Problem:**
Let $f(x)=x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ for $0<x<1$ and $f(x)=0$ else. Let $\{r_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be an enumeration of rationals.

Define $g(x)=\sum_n\frac{f(x-r_n)}{2^n}$.

Show that

(1) $g\in L^1(m)$.

(2) $g$ is discontinuous everywhere and unbounded on every interval. It remains so after a correction on a set of measure $0$.

(3) $g^2<\infty$ a.e. but $g^2$ is not integrable over any interval.

*Since $f$ is non negative, by applying monotone convergence theorem I could solve 1. But I'm completely blind about 2 and 3 even about how to start. Any kind of suggestions will be appreciated.*

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: On the interval $(a,b)$, pick a rational $r$ such that $a<r<b$.  Note that $g(x) \ge 2^{-n} f(x-r)$, where $n$ is such that $r = r_n$.

Comment: Since $f\geq 0$, indeed $g(x)\geq 2^{-n}f(x-r_n)$ for all $n$.Did you mean this inequality for $g$ to be discontinuous near any $r_n \in (a,b)?$. Then it solves the $2$nd one.Thank you..

Comment: It solves the third one as well.  Think about $\int_{(a,b)} f(x-r_n)^2 \, dx$.

Comment: But what's about the 3rd? I can't see the solution coming out of your argument? Would you please explain?